# Install Cython with python3 in Docker

Tags: ubuntu, python, docker, python3

I'm using a Docker image from `tensorflow` with `python3`:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3
```

I need `Cython` for a 3rd party library to be there, so I do

```
RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && \
    python get-pip.py && \
    rm get-pip.py

RUN \ 
    pip install --no-cache-dir Cython
```

The problem is that after that I can see `Cython` from `python`, but not from `python3`:

```
root@fdb5bb783cf9:/darkflow# python3 -c "import Cython; print(Cython.__version__)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'Cython'
root@fdb5bb783cf9:/darkflow# python -c "import Cython; print(Cython.__version__)"
0.25.2
```

Comment: Are you sure the image you are using has python3? is tagged as it is... but I repeat, are you sure?

Comment: Thanks I have just realized I have missed something: `apt-get install python3-pip`, and `pip3 install --no-cache-dir Cython`, after that it worked!

Comment: Ok so put the answer yourself and mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that the solution was to use `pip3` to run `Cython` install as well as `python3` to run the `setup.py` of the library, so:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip
```

and

```
RUN \ 
    pip3 install --no-cache-dir Cython
```

and the library layer

```
RUN \
    cd lib && \
    python3 setup.py
```

The last one could have been `pip3 install .` to install globally using `pip3`.

This time doing

```
RUN python3 -c "import Cython; print(Cython.__version__)"
```

I had `Cython` there: `0.25.2`